# how to capture the cookie param from Facebook referrer

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, fiddler, referrer

I'm not sure about the security implications of this and if its privileged info. But I want to know if I can capture the header information from a Facebook link hitting my page. I can capture the referrer fine using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and I get the URI. But the information is incomplete. I'm looking at fiddler2 and I want to capture the header cookie which has encoded JSON with info such as the `FBID`.  I'm looking to build my own analytic engine, but would be happy to know if I can get this with Google analytics or a G-analytics plugin. Or maybe another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google analytics does not provide a way to do this, but a few other analytics tools out there do (for instance, Omniture SiteCatalyst).

But as for your own home-baked solution, all headers sent to your script should show up in the $_SERVER array.  For debug/dev purposes, you can look at all the headers sent by just dumping out the $_SERVER array (< pre > tags are for if you are looking at it from a browser. If you're running command-line, just do the print_r()):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
```

...and you would simply refer to whatever header value with `$_SERVER['whatever']`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately though Facebook doesn't forward the same info from fiddler into the server variable :/ . I'll take a look at these analytics plugins.

Comment: @Chamilyan: hmm...that can't be right...it should show all headers sent, even arbitrary ones. For instance, if I use fiddler to add an arbitrary header of `someVar: someValue` it shows up as `$_SERVER['HTTP_SOMEVAR'] => 'someValue'` Are you sure the entry in fiddler you are looking at for facebook is actually to your server?